# Why do I get permission denied when I try use "make" to install something?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, makefile

I'm trying to install something and it's throwing me an error: `Permission denied` when I try to run `make` on it.

I'm not too fond of the universal rules of unix/linux and not too fond of user rights either.  My best guess is that the user I'm logged in as does not have the privileges to run `make` commands, but hopefully it's something else that's not permitting me to install.

Why do I get `Permission denied` and what should I check or configure in order to attempt permission be granted?

**EDIT**

Error Message:

```
gcc -I. -O3 -o pp-inspector  pp-inspector.c
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: [pp-inspector] Error 127 (ignored)
gcc -I. -O3 -c tis-vnc.c -DLIBOPENSSL -DLIBOPENSSLNEW -DLIBIDN -DHAVE_PR29_H -DLIBMYSQLCLIENT -DLIBPOSTGRES -DHAVE_MATH_H -I/usr/include/mysql
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [tis-vnc.o] Error 127
```

Comment: i tried, but got the same error as in the first comment to Jarryd's answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On many source packages (e.g. for most GNU software), the building system may know about the `DESTDIR` *make* variable, so you can often do:

```
 make install DESTDIR=/tmp/myinst/
 sudo cp -va /tmp/myinst/ /
```

The advantage of this approach is that `make install`  don't need to run as root, so you cannot end up with files compiled as root (or root-owned files in your build tree).

Answer (score 30):

Execute `chmod 777 -R scripts/`, it worked fine for me ;)

Comment: Works!!! Just do `chmod 777 -R yourDirName` where `yourDirName` is the path to the directory containing the makeFile

Comment: https://preview.redd.it/121ereqww0f31.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=4588f8f1dfe86d241e940644a3077564dadd7f1e

Comment: chmod 777 means everybody is allowed to read write execute. It is a workaround but it is not recommended for security reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Giving us the whole error message would be much more useful. If it's for make install then you're probably trying to install something to a system directory and you're not root. If you have root access then you can run

```
sudo make install
```

or log in as root and do the whole process as root.

Comment: thanks, updated my question and also tried `sudo` but got the error message `ccq is not allowed to run sudo on cpanel03`

Comment: i guess i got the answer to my question now

Comment: So it's saying you're not allowed to run gcc. It looks like you're on a cpanel installation, you might not even be allowed to run gcc.

Comment: yeah im on cpanel... is there any other way to "make" the installation?  or is that only possible via the command line

Comment: I don't know what your setup is. Are you on a machine that you own or a web host's machine. If you are on your own machine then there is always a way. If you are on a web host who has given you cpanel access to manage your web server then you probably can't install software like that.

Comment: If you can get access to another host of the same architecture and OS version, you can run gcc there and then just move the binaries to the web server. If you are not "fond of" your operating system it might get more involved than you like, though.

Comment: @CheeseConQueso If you got the answer to your question, please write that down for all to know.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is frequently with 'secure' setup of mountpoints, such as /tmp

If they are mounted `noexec` (check with `cat /etc/mtab` and or `sudo mount`) then there is no permission to execute any binaries or build scripts from within the (temporary) folder.

E.g. to remount temporarily:

```
 sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Or to change permanently, remove `noexec` in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! You made a small typo 'mounte' -> 'mount'

Comment: @FrankMartin Cheers, fixed!

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar error message as you, although listing a particular file:

```
$ make
make: execvp: ../HoughLineExtractor/houghlineextractor.hh: Permission denied
make: *** [../HoughLineAccumulator/houghlineaccumulator.o] Error 127

$ sudo make
make: execvp: ../HoughLineExtractor/houghlineextractor.hh: Permission denied
make: *** [../HoughLineAccumulator/houghlineaccumulator.o] Error 127
```

In my case, I forgot to add a trailing slash to indicate continuation of the line as shown:

```
${LINEDETECTOR_OBJECTS}:\
    ../HoughLineAccumulator/houghlineaccumulator.hh  # <-- missing slash!!
    ../HoughLineExtractor/houghlineextractor.hh
```

Hope that helps someone else who lands here from a search engine.