# Can't run program after putting the compiled file to the folder

Tags: c++, makefile

In my `Makefile` I'm trying to specify, that I want to save the compiled executable file to `/dvoram64/` folder. Before, when I tried to save it diretly to `/` everything worked all right, but now I get this message after calling `make run`:

```
ubuntu@pa2:~/Project$ make run
Makefile:37: warning: overriding commands for target `dvoram64/main'
Makefile:34: warning: ignoring old commands for target `dvoram64/main'
make: Circular dvoram64/main <- dvoram64/main dependency dropped.
mkdir -p dvoram64
g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -g -c src/main.cpp -o dvoram64/main
./dvoram64/main
make: execvp: ./dvoram64/main: Permission denied
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
#macros
CC=g++
CCFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -g
LBFLAGS=-lncurses -pthread
Remove=rm -rf
Objects=dvoram64/main
Doxygen=Doxyfile
RUN=./dvoram64/main
CPATH=objects/

#generates final binary and documentation
all: $(Objects) $(Doxygen)
    make compile
    make doc

#build into final binary
compile: $(RUN)

#run program
run: $(RUN)
    $(RUN)

clean:
    $(Remove) doc/
    $(Remove) dvoram64

#generate documentation in '<login>/doc' folder
doc: $(Doxygen) src/*
    ( cd src | doxygen $(Doxygen))

#rules to make objects ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(RUN): $(Objects)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(Objects) -o $(RUN) $(LBFLAGS)

dvoram64/main: src/main.cpp
    mkdir -p dvoram64
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp -o dvoram64/main
```

Could anybody tell me, what causes that and how to fix it?

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106536/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-when-i-try-use-make-to-install-something), also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665180/why-is-make-complaining-about-circular-dependencies)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any makefile generator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems. First:

```
RUN=./dvoram64/main

$(RUN): $(Objects)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(Objects) -o $(RUN) $(LBFLAGS)

dvoram64/main: src/main.cpp
    mkdir -p dvoram64
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp -o dvoram64/main
```

You have two rules for the same target(`dvoram64/main`). Which do you want to use? Why do you have two? Remove one of them.

Next:

```
Objects=dvoram64/main

RUN=./dvoram64/main

$(RUN): $(Objects)
    ...
```

You have two variables for (essentially) the same thing, which is untidy but not illegal. But You make one the prerequisite of the other. A thing cannot be it's own prerequisite, and Make must correct the error for you. You should rethink this.

Next:

```
RUN=./dvoram64/main

run: $(RUN)
    $(RUN)

dvoram64/main: src/main.cpp
    mkdir -p dvoram64
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp -o dvoram64/main
```

You have lost track of whether `dvoram64/main` should be an object file or an executable file. You have two rules to build it; one builds an executable, the other an object. You name it `main`, which sounds like an executable file, but you put that name in a variable called `Objects`. And in the end you build an object file and try to execute it.

You can save yourself some trouble by keeping the makefile as free of redundancy as possible. And when the big target fails, try the little targets one at a time to narrow nown the scope of the problem.

Comment: TY for the answer... nicely explained